# ios Unprocessable Entity while SignUp in Quickblox

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am developing a chatting app and i have added Quickblox framework for chat, but while signup with new user getting following error:

```
Request URL:https://api.quickblox.com/users.json
Request method: POST
Request parameters:{
user =     {
    login = 8306706078;
    password = 12345;
};
}
Request headers: {
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
"QB-SDK" = "iOS 2.0.12";
"QB-Token" = 98b2213918ec59f8d669f021c7792f82a7f40dc3;
"QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
}
error.description [QBResponse], status: 422
Response headers: {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Tue, 27 Jan 2015 21:41:35 GMT";
"QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2015-01-27 23:40:49 UTC";
"QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
Server = "nginx/1.0.15";
Status = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
"X-Request-Id" = 14e6f057f03d5913fafea2dbae6754be;
"X-Runtime" = "0.015577";
"X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
}
```

i used following code...

Created session in appdelegate

```
[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", "") message:[response.error description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", "") otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}];
```

Calling signUp API in signViewController:

```
QBUUser *userTmp = [QBUUser user];
    userTmp.login = phone;
    userTmp.password = pswd;

    [QBRequest signUp:userTmp successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user) {

        BeLokaalUser *beLokaalUser = [BeLokaalUser user];

        beLokaalUser.fullName = userTmp.fullName;
        beLokaalUser.login = user.login;
        beLokaalUser.password = user.password;
        beLokaalUser.phone = userTmp.phone;
        beLokaalUser.email = userTmp.email;
        beLokaalUser.country = self.txtCountry.text;

        [self dismissView];
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

        NSLog(@"error.description %@",response.description);

        [self dismissView];
    }];
```

Comment: Sry I am going off the topic. I am also trying to signup new user using Quickblox api using free account. Can you please let me know that to create new user is there any requirement for paid account?

Comment: @Arti Did you find any way to resolve this error? I am also facing same issue. In my case sample app is running fine in iPhone (iOS 8.1) but same app shows 422 error in iPad (iOS 8.1.2).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the password should contain 8 letters. I stuck on that error for more than 5 hours. :(

Comment: There should be an error explanation in logs all the time

Comment: Hi PK86, Can you help me how to generate signature for https://api.quickblox.com/session.json  to pass as a payload?